# how can I attach the file in Codeigniter which i have created through coding?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have created a pdf file from coding and i want that pdf file to send by attaching in the email.Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use codeigniter attach function..

```
$this->email->attach()
```

it enables you to send an attachment. Put the file path/name in the first parameter.

eg..

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/yourfile.pdf');

$this->email->send();
```

go through the user guides..
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: thanks for above help but what my problems is once i created the file it downloads automatically and i have sent that file via email attachment

Comment: ok... downloads in your server or u mean client side(using force download).... if in ur server, thn u can give the downloaded file path to above code...if not thn , save(copy) the file in your server while creating it  and give that path to the attachment... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read about it here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/email.html

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo2.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo3.jpg');

$this->email->send();
```

**Remember that you can only attach files from your own server.**